# Sybase query: How can I sort the extraction (by well formed columns)

Tags: performance, sybase, unix, query-performance

community 
I built a *Sybase query* statement in a script (using the isql command/line ) below is the code:

My script contains:

```
 isql -U databasename_dba -P password  <<EOF!
    select  customerid, notional, counterparty2 from table_1  inner join table_2
    on id = id2 
    go
    quit
    EOF!
```

I'm getting this:

[image: Current output]

My **desired output** would be:

[image: Desidered output]

Thinking that extracting just the data (excluding the headers) might fix the output. I added in my code `-b`

```
isql -U databasename_dba -P password  -b <<EOF!
```

But the output doesn't change that much:

[image: Second output]

Thanks in advance for your ideas

Comment: Try adding-w parameter, this would dictate size of window. You may use -w99999 and output can be copied to a text editor. You could see that in the correct or desired format.

Comment: Hi @ Learning_DBAdmin it worked, now the extraction looks as I wanted, how can I rate you? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding-w parameter, this would dictate size of window. You may use -w99999 and output can be copied to a text editor. You could see that in the correct or desired format.

This seems to be working and hence adding it as an answer.